# How to process Read Model in CQRS

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, wolkenkit

We want to implement cqrs in our new design. We have some doubts in processing command handler and read model. We got understand that while processing commands we should take optimistic lock on aggregateId. But what approach should be considered while processing readModels. Should we take lock on entire readModel or on aggregateId or never take lock while processing read model.

case 1.   when take lock on entire readmodel -> it is safest but is not good in term of speed.

case 2 - take lock on aggregateId. Here two issues may arise. if we take lock aggregateId wise -> then what if read model server restarts. It does not know from where it starts again.

case 3 - Never take lock. in ths approach,  I think data may be in corrputed state. For eg say an order inserted event is generated and thorugh some workflow/saga, order updated event took place as well. what if order updated event comes first and order inserted event is not yet processed ?

Hope I am able to address my issue.

Comment: Does it matter? When using CQRS you typically work under the assumption of eventual consistency. You usually pump the events into a queue, which guarantees you the order of execution another worker, gets the items from the queue and updates the read store. If in one request the order appears not to be yet closed updated or not, its usually not that bad since the read store is just informational. Your authoritative storage is the write store (used to populate your aggregate by replaying the events)

Comment: readStore is not just informational, I think all your UI data is coming from ReadModel not from aggregates(write model). and say we have multiple workers that is processing the event bus. One worker has pop the order placed event. being processed and mean while anohter worker pop the orderUpdated event. Now there will be problem if first workder did not actually yet finisted insertion of order.

Comment: We are serializing read model updates via bus or stream. If you have a single worker process that read events from the stream, and applies to the read model - you don't need a lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not process events concurrently in the Readmodel then there is no need for a lock. This is the case when you have a single instance of the Readmodel, possible in a Microservice, that poll for events and process them sequentially.

If you have a synchronous Readmodel (i.e. in the same process as the Writemodel/Aggregate) then most probably you will need locking.

An important thing to keep in mind is that a Readmodel most probably differs from the Writemodel. There could be a lot of Writemodel types whos events are projected in the same Readmodel. For example, in an ecommerce shop you could have a `ListOfProducts` that projects event from `Vendor` and from `Product` Aggregates. This means that, when we speak about a Readmodel we cannot simply refer to the "Aggregate" because there is not single Aggregate involved. In the case of ecommerce, when we say "the Aggregate" we might refer to the `Product` Aggregate or `Vendor` Aggregate.

But what to lock? Here depends on the database technology. You should lock the smallest *affected* read entity or collection that can be locked. In a Readmodel that consist of a list of products (read entities, not aggregates!), when an event that affects only one product you should lock only that product (i.e. `ProductTitleRenamed`).

If an event affects more products then you should lock the entire collection. For example, `VendorWasBlocked` affects all the products (it should remove all the products from that vendor).

You need the locking for the events that have non-idempotent side effects, for the case where the Readmodel's updater fails during the processing of an event, if you want to retry/resume from where it left. If the event has idempotent side effects then it can be retried safely.

In order to know from where to resume in case of a failed Readmodel, you could store inside the Readmodel the sequence of the last processed event. In this case, if the entity update succeeds then the last processed event's sequence is also saved. If it fails then you know that the event was not processed.

Comment: Thanks Constantin. Say we have two order placed event happened. Now in read model both entities are independents. But as readModel processing the events, should the second order place event, wait untill first order placed event completely processed, other wise read model can;t keep its state which event it has processed required if we need to restart server. We are actually working on nodejs which is async.

Comment: @RohitBansal it depends. If you serialize the event processing (so if you wait) then you must keep track only the last event processed. If you don't serialize and execute in parallel then you should store all the event IDs that you have processed. I don't see how you can safely execute in parallel events because you need to process the events from an Aggregate in the order they were generated. Otherwise you process ProductTitleUpdated(id:123) before ProductCreated(id:123)

Comment: @RohitBansal in other words, you should serialize/wait at least per Aggregate stream

Comment: Thats what i am asking. If processing in serial - then just need to keep track of last event id but in this case we may not be able to distribute load. am I correct ?

Comment: @RohitBansal you can. I gave an answer to this. I search it in show it to you.

Comment: @RohitBansal I can't seem to find it. Anyway, the idea is that if you can find a key by which you can distribute the load in such a way that concurrent updates of the same read entity is avoided then you can distribute the load. Then you have serialization per shard only.

Comment: @RohitBansal so it depends a lot on the Readmodel

Answer (score 1):

> For eg say an order inserted event is generated and thorugh some workflow/saga, order updated event took place as well. what if order updated event comes first and order inserted event is not yet processed ?

Read models are usually easier to reason about if you think about them polling for ordered sequences of events, rather than reacting to unordered notifications.

A single read model might depend on events from more than one aggregate, so aggregate locking is unlikely to be your most general answer.

That also means, if we are polling, that we need to keep track of the position of multiple streams of data.  In other words, our read model probably includes meta data that tells us what version of each source was used.

The locking is likely to depend on the nature of your backing store / cache.  But an optimistic approach

1. read the current representation
2. compute the new representation
3. compare and swap

is, again, usually easy to reason about.

Comment: Thanks. Say we have two order placed event happened. Now in read model both entities are independents. But as readModel processing the events, should the second order place event, wait untill first order placed event completely processed, other wise read model can;t keep its state which event it has processed required if we need to restart server. We are actually working on nodejs which is async.